# Django can't close persistent Mysql connection

Tags: python, mysql, django

**Problem:**

Our Django application includes zipping large folders, which takes too long (up to **48** hours) so the Django connection with the database gets timed out and throws: "*MySQL server has gone away error*".

**Description:**

We have a **Django version==3.2.1** application whose **CONN_MAX_AGE** value is set to **1500(seconds)**. The default **wait_timeout** in Mysql(MariaDB) is **8 hours**.

ExportStatus table has the following attributes:

1. **package_size**
2. **zip_time**

**Our application works this way:**

1. Zip the folders
2. set the attribute '**package_size**' of **ExportStatus** table after zipping and save in the database.
3. set the attribute '**zip_time**' of **ExportStatus** table after zipping and save in the database.

Notice the setting of the columns' values in database. These require django connection with database, which gets timedout after long zipping process. Thus throws the ***MySQL server gone away*** error.

**What we have tried so far:**

1. ```
   from django.db import close_old_connections`
   close_old_connections()
   ```

   This solution doesn't work.
2. Just after zipping, if the time taken is more than 25 minutes, we close all the connections and ensure new connection as:

   ```
   from django.db import connections
   for connection in connections.all():
       try:
           # hack to check if the connection still persists with the database.
           with connection.cursor() as c:
           c.execute("DESCRIBE auth_group;")
           c.fetchall()
       except:
           connection.close()
           connection.ensure_connection()
   ```

Upon printing the value of the length of **connections.all()**, it is 2. What we don't understand is how Django persists those old connections and retrieves connections from the connection pool. When we close connections from **connections.all()**, aren't we closing all the connections in the thread pool?

We first set the **package_size** and then set the **zip_time**. The problem with this solution is that occasionally (not always), it throws the same error when setting the **zip_time** attribute. Sometimes, this solution does seem to work. There is no problem in setting the **package_size** but throws an error occasionally when setting the '**zip_time**' attribute. So our question is if we already reset connections after zipping, why does this still take a stale connection from the connection pool and throws the MySQL server gone away error? Do we have any way to close all the old persistent connections and recreate new ones?

Comment: have you got any solution to it?

Comment: turns out that the wait_timeout was set to just 25 minutes, which is why connection was being reset every 25 minutes.

Comment: alright, thanks budy,